# How to get values from a multichoice listview alertdialog

Tags: java, android

I have an ArrayList of Person class containing age and name of the person. In the adapter (extends BaseAdapter), I have two TextViews(for setting the values of age and name) and a checkbox. This is needed to be inflated into alert dialog.

How can I implement this using multichoice of the alert dialog.

Also I did look at some examples but did not understand about the boolean[] values attribute in the alert dialog, this is the code I have so far but it still needs to implement that multichoice mode..

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:clickable="true"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice">
    </ListView>
```

My alertdialog..

```
  AlertDialog.Builder ab=new AlertDialog.Builder(CustomListActivity.this);
                LayoutInflater linf=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View v1=linf.inflate(R.layout.dialog_list, null);
                ab.setView(v1);
                //ab.setTitle("Select a group");

                lv=(ListView) v1.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                 ma=new MyAdapter(CustomListActivity.this, plist);
                lv.setAdapter(ma);
```

And MYAdapter ..

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    Context ctx;
    ArrayList<Person> plist;
    LayoutInflater linf;
    public PersonHolder ph=null;


    public MyAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Person> plist) {
        super();
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.plist = plist;
    }

    public class PersonHolder
    {
        public TextView age;
        public TextView name;
        public CheckBox check;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return plist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return plist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        linf=(LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(ctx.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView=linf.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);
            ph=new PersonHolder();
            ph.age=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            ph.name=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            ph.check=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            convertView.setTag(ph);
        }
        else
        {
            ph=(PersonHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Person p=(Person) getItem(position);
        ph.age.setText(p.getAge());
        ph.name.setText(p.getName());
        ph.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              if(ph.check.isChecked())
//              {
                    ph.check.setSelected(arg1);
//              }
//              else
//              {
//                  ph.check.setSelected(false);
//              }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your adapter to following and just call `getSelected` on adapter.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    Context ctx;
    ArrayList<Person> plist;
    LayoutInflater linf;
    public PersonHolder ph=null;
    private ArrayList<Integer> selected=new ArrayList<Integer>();


    public MyAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Person> plist) {
        super();
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.plist = plist;
    }

    public class PersonHolder
    {
        public TextView age;
        public TextView name;
        public CheckBox check;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return plist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return plist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        linf=(LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(ctx.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView=linf.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);
            ph=new PersonHolder();
            ph.age=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            ph.name=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            ph.check=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            convertView.setTag(ph);
        }
        else
        {
            ph=(PersonHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Person p=(Person) getItem(position);
        ph.age.setText(p.getAge());
        ph.name.setText(p.getName());
        ph.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              if(ph.check.isChecked())
//              {
                    ph.check.setSelected(arg1);
                    if(arg1){ 
                        selected.add(position);
                    }else{
                        selected.remove(position);
                    }
//              }
//              else
//              {
//                  ph.check.setSelected(false);
//              }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
 public ArrayList<Integer> getSelected(){
     return selected;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a multichoice dialog myself, this is what i am doing, basically you need to catch each click to the listview and memorize whatever it is you selected/set there.

```
private void startDayPickerDialog() {

    String[] days = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dayNames);
    days = Arrays.copyOf(days, 7);

    final Adapter a = new Adapter(getActivity());

    AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
    .setTitle(R.string.repeat)
    .setAdapter(a, new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    }).setPositiveButton(R.string.done, new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    }).create();

    d.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> lv, View view, int position, long id) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            cb.setChecked(!cb.isChecked());
            a.getItem(position).setChecked(!a.getItem(position).isChecked());               
        }


    });

    d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    d.show();
}
```

Comment: This solution can be applied when the checkbox as well as the listview are in the dialog displaying activity..Here my situation is that my listview is in the activity..while the checkbox is in the adapter..but anyways through yours and Vipul's solution i did get and idea..and implemented it..thanks a lot..